# How can I have structured dtypes using sparse matrices (in scipy.sparse)?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have structured data that can be represented in `numpy` like this:

```
dtype = np.dtype([('a', 'f8'),
                  ('b', 'f8')])
X = np.zeros((3,4), dtype=dtype)
```

And would like to operate on a sparse version of it. Scipy has `sparse`, but I haven't figured out quite how to pull off *structured* data:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sparse

dtype = np.dtype([('a', 'f8'),
                  ('b', 'f8')])
X = np.zeros((3,4), dtype=dtype)
A, B = X['a'], X['b']
A[:] = np.arange(0, 12).reshape((3,4))

Xdok = sparse.dok_matrix(X, dtype=dtype)
Xcoo = Xdoc.tocoo()

# No supported conversion for structured type
# Xcsr = Xdok.tocsr()
# Xlil = Xdok.tolil()

# Cannot perform reduce with flexible type
# Xdok['a']

# 'coo_matrix' object is not subscriptable
# Xcoo['a']
```

I can get the `doc` and `coo` version, but then I can't slice out my keys (eg `Xdok['a']`), and from what I understand, `dok` and `coo` are inefficient at performing any sort of math.

Ultimately, I'm trying to represent Directed Graphs with multi-valued weights on the edges (eg `a` and `b`), and I need to be able to perform simple linear algebra on the graphs.

I've considered keeping an `a` sparse matrix separate from a `b` sparse matrix, but ultimately they'll be populated at exactly the same indexes, and I would rather keep all that data in one structure in memory.

Should I be using another lib than Scipy?

Comment: `coo` created with the appropriate `row, col, data` arrays uses those directly without processing.  Looks like the `dok` does as well.  But most of the `sparse` code, especially the `csr` format that implements math, works only with the standard numeric dtypes (using compiled code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [26]: M = sparse.coo_matrix(X)
In [27]: M.data
Out[27]: 
array([( 1., 0.), ( 2., 0.), ( 3., 0.), ( 4., 0.), ( 5., 0.), ( 6., 0.),
       ( 7., 0.), ( 8., 0.), ( 9., 0.), (10., 0.), (11., 0.)],
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8')])
In [28]: M.A
....
ValueError: unsupported data types in input

In [30]: M.tocsr()
...
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype([('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8')]),)
```

Conversion to (and from) `dok` is ok with the compound dtype:

```
In [31]: M.todok()
Out[31]: 
<3x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.void'>'
    with 11 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>
In [32]: _.items()
Out[32]: dict_items([((0, 1), (1., 0.)), ((1, 2), (6., 0.)), ((1, 3), (7., 0.)), ((2, 3), (11., 0.)), ((2, 0), (8., 0.)), ((1, 0), (4., 0.)), ((0, 3), (3., 0.)), ((2, 2), (10., 0.)), ((1, 1), (5., 0.)), ((2, 1), (9., 0.)), ((0, 2), (2., 0.))])
```

`dok` implements indexing:

```
In [33]: __[0,1]
Out[33]: (1., 0.)
```

The `M.data` array is structured, and can be accessed by field name.  But `coo` hasn't implemented any indexing:

```
In [34]: M.data['a']
Out[34]: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11.])
```

A `dok` is a subclass of dictionary, and apparently the elements are stored as dtype records:

```
In [39]: type(M.todok()[0,1])
Out[39]: numpy.void
In [40]: M.todok()[0,1]['a']
Out[40]: 1.0
```

But again, no provision in the `dok` indexing for accessing fields.

In sum, the sparse module was not written with compound dtypes in mind.  Its roots are in linear algebra (e.g. solving large sparse linear equations).  Where these dtypes work it is just using `numpy` arrays and elements without special handing.